# Running an application using maven

Tags: maven-2, spring-batch

I am trying to run an application using maven. I am very new to it. I got it installed and it is working properly. i am not able to run it. i am getting the following errors in the console: -

> [WARNING] repository metadata for: 'org.apache.maven.plugins' could not be retrieved from repository: central due to an error: Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
>   [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect`

What can i do to run my app? where am I lacking?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your system is behind a proxy server.  If so, create or update `settings.xml` in the `.m2` subfolder of your `home directory` and add the proxy section as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies).

You can use the proxy settings, which is likely to be present in your browser configuration. (In case of Internet Explorer : Tools -> Internet Options -> Connections -> LAN Settings)