# How to import source for EJB 3.1 in IntelliJ with pom.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish, intellij-idea, ejb-3.1

I'm going through the EJB 3.1 book from manning and having a terrible time trying to import the source code into IntelliJ using Maven 2.

Source is located at: http://action-bazaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk

After checking out the project and importing everything I try to run the maven build see the following errors:

```
Downloading: http://download.java.net/maven/2/org/glassfish/javax.ejb/3.1/javax.ejb-3.1.pom 
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.glassfish:javax.ejb:pom:3.1' from 
repository java.net2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect
```

**Error is:** 
Error transferring file: Connection timed out: connect

I'm behind a proxy but have successfully set my HTTP Proxy settings on the IDE.

The Pom.xml is located [here](http://action-bazaar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/chapter1/ActionBazaar/pom.xml):

**Question**
How can I resolve this or how can I import and run this project (just chapter1 for now) on IntelliJ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running an application using maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063694/running-an-application-using-maven)

Answer (score 0):

EJBs support in IntelliJ is applied through facets.
Enabling EJB Support:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/enabling-ejb-support.html

Alos useful:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/web-ejb-and-java-ee-application-facets.html

Hope this helps.